# Use jsonified html as actual html in React

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

I'm using the wikipedia API to call information from different searches.

This is how I call it:

```
const api = `${proxy}http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&section=0&prop=text&page=${this.state.value}`;
```

Then when I get it back I'm interested in the HTML. I get that through:

```
jsonObject.parse.text["*"]
```

Then I want to use this to create a replica of the wikipedia page. This is how I try recreate the wikipedia page:

```
ReactDOM.render(jsonObject.parse.text["*"], document.getElementById('root'))
```

It doesn't work as intended. Can anyone explain why? The resulting page just has a long string. The result is something along the lines of:

`<div class="mw-parser-output"><div class="shortdescription nomobile noexcerpt noprint searchaux" style="display:none">A four-wheeled motor vehicle used to transport people</div> <div role="note" class="hatnote navigation-not-searchable">For broader coverage of this topic, see <a href="/wiki/Motor_vehicle" title="Motor vehicle">Motor vehicle</a>.</div> <div role="note" class="hatnote navigation-not-searchable">For other uses, see <a href="/wiki/Car_(disambiguation)" class="mw-disambig" title="Car (disambiguation)">Car (disambiguation)</a> and <a href="/wiki/Automobile_(disambiguation)" class="mw-disambig" title="Automobile (disambiguation)">Automobile (disambiguation)</a>.</div> <p class="mw-empty-elt"> </p> <table class="infobox" style="width:22em"><tbody><tr><th colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font-size:125%;font-weight:bold">Car</th></tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><a href="/wiki/File:401_Gridlock.jpg" class="image"><img alt="401 Gridlock.jpg" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/401_Gridlock.jpg/300px-401_Gridlock.jpg" decoding="async" width="300" height="200" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/401_Gridlock.jpg/450px-401_Gridlock.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/401_Gridlock.jpg/600px-401_Gridlock.jpg 2x" data-file-width="1600" data-file-height="1066" /></a><div>Cars and <a href="/wiki/Truck" title="Truck">trucks</a> driving on <a href="/wiki/Ontario_Highway_401" title="Ontario Highway 401">Highway 401</a> in <a href="/wiki/Ontario" title="Ontario">Ontario</a>, Canada</div></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Classification</th><td>Vehicle</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Industry</th><td>Various</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Application</th><td><a href="/wiki/Transportation" class="mw-redirect" title="Transportation">Transportation</a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Fuel source</th><td><a href="/wiki/Gasoline" title="Gasoline">Gasoline</a>, <a href="/wiki/Diesel_fuel" title="Diesel fuel">diesel</a>, <a href="/wiki/Natural_gas" title="Natural gas">natural gas</a>, <a href="/wiki/Electric_car" title="Electric car">electric</a>, <a href="/wiki/Hydrogen" title="Hydrogen">hydrogen</a>, <a href="/wiki/Solar_energy" title="Solar energy">solar</a>, <a href="/wiki/Vegetable_oil" title="Vegetable oil">vegetable oil</a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Powered</th><td>Yes</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Self-propelled</th><td>Yes</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Wheels</th><td>3–4</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Axles</th><td>2</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Inventor</th><td><a href="/wiki/Karl_Benz" title="Karl Benz">Karl Benz</a><sup id="cite_ref-stein_1-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-stein-1">&#91;1&#93;</a></sup></td></tr></tbody></table> <p>A <b>car</b> (or <b>automobile</b>) is a wheeled <a href="/wiki/Motor_vehicle" title="Motor vehicle">motor vehicle</a> used for <a href="/wiki/Transportation" class="mw-redirect" title="Transportation">transportation</a>. Most definitions of <i>car</i> say they run primarily on roads, seat one to eight people, have four <a href="/wiki/Tyre_(wheel)" class="mw-redirect" title="Tyre (wheel)">tires</a>, and mainly transport people rather than goods.<sup id="cite_ref-2" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-2">&#91;2&#93;</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-OEDmotrcar_3-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-OEDmotrcar-3">&#91;3&#93;</a></sup> </p><p>Cars came into global use during the 20th century, and <a href="/wiki/Developed_country" title="Developed country">developed economies</a> depend on them. The year 1886 is regarded as the birth year of the modern car when German inventor <a href="/wiki/Karl_Benz" title="Karl Benz">Karl Benz</a> patented his <a href="/wiki/Benz_Patent-Motorwagen" title="Benz Patent-Motorwagen">Benz Patent-Motorwagen</a>. Cars became widely available in the early 20th century. One of the first cars accessible to the masses was the 1908 <a href="/wiki/Ford_Model_T" title="Ford Model T">Model T</a>, an American car manufactured by the <a href="/wiki/Ford_Motor_Company" title="Ford Motor Company">Ford Motor Company</a>. Cars were rapidly adopted in the US, where they replaced <a href="/wiki/Draft_animal" class="mw-redirect" title="Draft animal">animal-drawn</a> <a href="/wiki/Carriage" title="Carriage">carriages</a> and carts, but took much longer to be accepted in Western Europe and other parts of the world.<sup class="noprint Inline-Template Template-Fact" style="white-space:nowrap;">&#91;<i><a href="/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed" title="Wikipedia:Citation needed"><span title="This claim needs references to reliable sources. (August 2019)">citation needed</span></a></i>&#93;</sup> </p><p>Cars have controls for driving, parking, passenger comfort, and a variety of lights. Over the decades, additional features and controls have been added to vehicles, making them progressively more complex, but also more reliable and easier to operate.<sup class="noprint Inline-Template Template-Fact" style="white-space:nowrap;">&#91;<i><a href="/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed" title="Wikipedia:Citation needed"><span title="This claim needs references to reliable sources. (August 2019)">citation needed</span></a></i>&#93;</sup> These include rear reversing cameras, <a href="/wiki/Automobile_air_conditioning" title="Automobile air conditioning">air conditioning</a>, <a href="/wiki/Automotive_navigation_system" title="Automotive navigation system">navigation systems</a>, and <a href="/wiki/In-car_entertainment" title="In-car entertainment">in-car entertainment</a>. Most cars in use in the 2010s are propelled by an <a href="/wiki/Internal_combustion_engine" title="Internal combustion engine">internal combustion engine</a>, fueled by the <a href="/wiki/Combustion" title="Combustion">combustion</a> of <a href="/wiki/Fossil_fuel" title="Fossil fuel">fossil fuels</a>. <a href="/wiki/Electric_car" title="Electric car">Electric cars</a>, which were invented early in the <a href="/wiki/History_of_the_automobile" title="History of the automobile">history of the car</a>, became commercially available in the 2000s and have the potential to cost less to buy than gasoline cars in the early 2020s.<sup id="cite_ref-4" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-4">&#91;4&#93;</a></sup> </p><p>There are costs and benefits to car use. The costs to the individual include acquiring the vehicle, interest payments (if the car is financed), repairs and <a href="/wiki/Auto_maintenance" class="mw-redirect" title="Auto maintenance">maintenance</a>, fuel, <a href="/wiki/Depreciation" title="Depreciation">depreciation</a>, driving time, <a href="/wiki/Parking_fee" class="mw-redirect" title="Parking fee">parking fees</a>, taxes, and insurance.<sup id="cite_ref-racv_5-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-racv-5">&#91;5&#93;</a></sup> The costs to society include <a href="/wiki/Maintaining_road" class="mw-redirect" title="Maintaining road">maintaining roads</a>, <a href="/wiki/Land_use" title="Land use">land use</a>, <a href="/wiki/Road_congestion" class="mw-redirect" title="Road congestion">road congestion</a>, <a href="/wiki/Air_pollution" title="Air pollution">air pollution</a>, <a href="/wiki/Public_health" title="Public health">public health</a>, health care, and disposing of the vehicle at the end of its life. <a href="/wiki/Traffic_collisions" class="mw-redirect" title="Traffic collisions">Traffic collisions</a> are the largest cause of injury-related deaths worldwide.<sup id="cite_ref-who_stats_6-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-who_stats-6">&#91;6&#93;</a></sup> </p><p> The personal benefits include on-demand transportation, mobility, independence, and convenience.<sup id="cite_ref-setright_7-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-setright-7">&#91;7&#93;</a></sup> The societal benefits include economic benefits, such as job and wealth creation from the <a href="/wiki/Automotive_industry" title="Automotive industry">automotive industry</a>, transportation provision, societal well-being from leisure and travel opportunities, and revenue generation from the <a href="/wiki/Category:Vehicle_taxes" title="Category:Vehicle taxes">taxes</a>. People's ability to move flexibly from place to place has far-reaching implications for the nature of societies.<sup id="cite_ref-parking_8-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-parking-8">&#91;8&#93;</a></sup> There are around 1 billion cars in use worldwide. The numbers are increasing rapidly, especially in <a href="/wiki/Automotive_industry_in_China" title="Automotive industry in China">China</a>, <a href="/wiki/Automotive_industry_in_India" title="Automotive industry in India">India</a> and other <a href="/wiki/Newly_industrialized_country" title="Newly industrialized country">newly industrialized countries</a>.<sup id="cite_ref-plunkettresearch.com_9-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-plunkettresearch.com-9">&#91;9&#93;</a></sup></p><div class="mw-references-wrap"><ol class="references"> <li id="cite_note-stein-1"><span class="mw-cite-backlink"><b><a href="#cite_ref-stein_1-0">^</a></b></span> <span class="error mw-ext-cite-error" lang="en" dir="ltr">Cite error: The named reference <code>stein</code> was invoked but never defined (see the <a href="/wiki/Help:Cite_errors/Cite_error_references_no_text" title="Help:Cite errors/Cite error references no text">help page</a>). </span></li> <li id="cite_note-2"><span class="mw-cite-backlink"><b><a href="#cite_ref-2">^</a></b></span> <span class="reference-text"><cite class="citation book">Fowler, H.W.; Fowler, F.G., eds. (1976). <i>Pocket Oxford Dictionary</i>. Oxford University Press. <a href="/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number" title="International Standard Book Number">ISBN</a>&#160;<a href="/wiki/Special:BookSources/978-0198611134" title="Special:BookSources/978-0198611134"><bdi>978-0198611134</bdi></a>.</cite><span title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Abook&amp;rft.genre=book&amp;rft.btitle=Pocket+Oxford+Dictionary&amp;rft.pub=Oxford+University+Press&amp;rft.date=1976&amp;rft.isbn=978-0198611134&amp;rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Fen.wikipedia.org%3ACar" class="Z3988"></span><style data-mw-deduplicate="TemplateStyles:r886058088">.mw-parser-output cite.citation{font-style:inherit}.mw-parser-output .citation q{quotes:"\"""\"""'""'"}.mw-parser-output .citation .cs1-lock-free a{background:url("//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Lock-green.svg/9px-Lock-green.svg.png")no-repeat;background-position:right .1em center}.mw-parser-output .citation .cs1-lock-limited a,.mw-parser-output .citation .cs1-lock-registration a{background:url("//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Lock-gray-alt-2.svg/9px-Lock-gray-alt-2.svg.png")no-repeat;background-position:right .1em center}.mw-parser-output .citation .cs1-lock-subscription a{background:url("//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Lock-red-alt-2.svg/9px-Lock-red-alt-2.svg.png")no-repeat;background-position:right .1em center}.mw-parser-output .cs1-subscription,.mw-parser-output .cs1-registration{color:#555}.mw-parser-output .cs1-subscription span,.mw-parser-output .cs1-registration span{border-bottom:1px dotted;cursor:help}.mw-parser-output .cs1-ws-icon a{background:url("//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4c/Wikisource-logo.svg/12px-Wikisource-logo.svg.png")no-repeat;background-position:right .1em center}.mw-parser-output code.cs1-code{color:inherit;background:inherit;border:inherit;padding:inherit}.mw-parser-output .cs1-hidden-error{display:none;font-size:100%}.mw-parser-output .cs1-visible-error{font-size:100%}.mw-parser-output .cs1-maint{display:none;color:#33aa33;margin-left:0.3em}.mw-parser-output .cs1-subscription,.mw-parser-output .cs1-registration,.mw-parser-output .cs1-format{font-size:95%}.mw-parser-output .cs1-kern-left,.mw-parser-output .cs1-kern-wl-left{padding-left:0.2em}.mw-parser-output .cs1-kern-right,.mw-parser-output .cs1-kern-wl-right{padding-right:0.2em}</style></span> </li> <li id="cite_note-OEDmotrcar-3"><span class="mw-cite-backlink"><b><a href="#cite_ref-OEDmotrcar_3-0">^</a></b></span> <span class="error mw-ext-cite-error" lang="en" dir="ltr">Cite error: The named reference <code>OEDmotrcar</code> was invoked but never defined (see the <a href="/wiki/Help:Cite_errors/Cite_error_references_no_text" title="Help:Cite errors/Cite error references no text">help page</a>). </span></li> <li id="cite_note-4"><span class="mw-cite-backlink"><b><a href="#cite_ref-4">^</a></b></span> <span class="reference-text"><cite class="citation web"><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="https://cleantechnica.com/2019/08/09/ev-price-parity-coming-soon-claims-vw-executive/">"EV Price Parity Coming Soon, Claims VW Executive"</a>. <i>CleanTechnica</i>. 9 August 2019<span class="reference-accessdate">. Retrieved <span class="nowrap">10 August</span> 2019</span>.</cite><span title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Ajournal&amp;rft.genre=unknown&amp;rft.jtitle=CleanTechnica&amp;rft.atitle=EV+Price+Parity+Coming+Soon%2C+Claims+VW+Executive&amp;rft.date=2019-08-09&amp;rft_id=https%3A%2F%2Fcleantechnica.com%2F2019%2F08%2F09%2Fev-price-parity-coming-soon-claims-vw-executive%2F&amp;rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Fen.wikipedia.org%3ACar" class="Z3988"></span><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r886058088"/></span> </li> <li id="cite_note-racv-5"><span class="mw-cite-backlink"><b><a href="#cite_ref-racv_5-0">^</a></b></span> <span class="reference-text"><cite class="citation web"><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="https://web.archive.org/web/20091007121101/http://www.racv.com.au/wps/wcm/connect/racv/Internet/Primary/my%2Bcar/advice%2B_%2Binformation/vehicle%2Boperating%2Bcosts/">"Car Operating Costs"</a>. RACV. Archived from <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.racv.com.au/wps/wcm/connect/racv/Internet/Primary/my+car/advice+_+information/vehicle+operating+costs/">the original</a> on 7 October 2009<span class="reference-accessdate">. Retrieved <span class="nowrap">22 December</span> 2009</span>.</cite><span title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Abook&amp;rft.genre=unknown&amp;rft.btitle=Car+Operating+Costs&amp;rft.pub=RACV&amp;rft_id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.racv.com.au%2Fwps%2Fwcm%2Fconnect%2Fracv%2FInternet%2FPrimary%2Fmy%2Bcar%2Fadvice%2B_%2Binformation%2Fvehicle%2Boperating%2Bcosts%2F&amp;rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Fen.wikipedia.org%3ACar" class="Z3988"></span><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r886058088"/></span> </li> <li id="cite_note-who_stats-6"><span class="mw-cite-backlink"><b><a href="#cite_ref-who_stats_6-0">^</a></b></span> <span class="reference-text"><cite class="citation book">Peden, Margie; Scurfield, Richard; Sleet, David; Mohan, Dinesh; Hyder, Adnan A.; Jarawan, Eva; Mathers, Colin, eds. (2004). <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://who.int/violence_injury_prevention/publications/road_traffic/world_report/en/"><i>World report on road traffic injury prevention</i></a>. World Health Organization. <a href="/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number" title="International Standard Book Number">ISBN</a>&#160;<a href="/wiki/Special:BookSources/92-4-156260-9" title="Special:BookSources/92-4-156260-9"><bdi>92-4-156260-9</bdi></a><span class="reference-accessdate">. Retrieved <span class="nowrap">24 June</span> 2008</span>.</cite><span title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Abook&amp;rft.genre=book&amp;rft.btitle=World+report+on+road+traffic+injury+prevention&amp;rft.pub=World+Health+Organization&amp;rft.date=2004&amp;rft.isbn=92-4-156260-9&amp;rft_id=http%3A%2F%2Fwho.int%2Fviolence_injury_prevention%2Fpublications%2Froad_traffic%2Fworld_report%2Fen%2F&amp;rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Fen.wikipedia.org%3ACar" class="Z3988"></span><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r886058088"/></span> </li> <li id="cite_note-setright-7"><span class="mw-cite-backlink"><b><a href="#cite_ref-setright_7-0">^</a></b></span> <span class="error mw-ext-cite-error" lang="en" dir="ltr">Cite error: The named reference <code>setright</code> was invoked but never defined (see the <a href="/wiki/Help:Cite_errors/Cite_error_references_no_text" title="Help:Cite errors/Cite error references no text">help page</a>). </span></li> <li id="cite_note-parking-8"><span class="mw-cite-backlink"><b><a href="#cite_ref-parking_8-0">^</a></b></span> <span class="reference-text"><cite class="citation book">Jakle, John A.; Sculle, Keith A. (2004). <i>Lots of Parking: Land Use in a Car Culture</i>. University of Virginia Press. <a href="/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number" title="International Standard Book Number">ISBN</a>&#160;<a href="/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-8139-2266-6" title="Special:BookSources/0-8139-2266-6"><bdi>0-8139-2266-6</bdi></a>.</cite><span title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Abook&amp;rft.genre=book&amp;rft.btitle=Lots+of+Parking%3A+Land+Use+in+a+Car+Culture&amp;rft.pub=University+of+Virginia+Press&amp;rft.date=2004&amp;rft.isbn=0-8139-2266-6&amp;rft.aulast=Jakle&amp;rft.aufirst=John+A.&amp;rft.au=Sculle%2C+Keith+A.&amp;rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Fen.wikipedia.org%3ACar" class="Z3988"></span><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r886058088"/></span> </li> <li id="cite_note-plunkettresearch.com-9"><span class="mw-cite-backlink"><b><a href="#cite_ref-plunkettresearch.com_9-0">^</a></b></span> <span class="reference-text"><cite class="citation web"><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110722031051/http://www.plunkettresearch.com/automobiles%20trucks%20market%20research/industry%20overview">"Automobile Industry Introduction"</a>. Plunkett Research. Archived from <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.plunkettresearch.com/Industries/AutomobilesTrucks/AutomobileTrends/tabid/89/Default.aspx">the original</a> on 22 July 2011.</cite><span title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Abook&amp;rft.genre=unknown&amp;rft.btitle=Automobile+Industry+Introduction&amp;rft.pub=Plunkett+Research&amp;rft_id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plunkettresearch.com%2FIndustries%2FAutomobilesTrucks%2FAutomobileTrends%2Ftabid%2F89%2FDefault.aspx&amp;rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Fen.wikipedia.org%3ACar" class="Z3988"></span><link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r886058088"/></span> </li> </ol></div> <!-- NewPP limit report Parsed by mw1289 Cached time: 20191013083710 Cache expiry: 2592000 Dynamic content: false Complications: [vary‐revision‐sha1] CPU time usage: 0.332 seconds Real time usage: 0.499 seconds Preprocessor visited node count: 1184/1000000 Preprocessor generated node count: 0/1500000 Post‐expand include size: 22522/2097152 bytes Template argument size: 3602/2097152 bytes Highest expansion depth: 13/40 Expensive parser function count: 4/500 Unstrip recursion depth: 0/20 Unstrip post‐expand size: 12133/5000000 bytes Number of Wikibase entities loaded: 0/400 Lua time usage: 0.152/10.000 seconds Lua memory usage: 3.95 MB/50 MB --> <!-- Transclusion expansion time report (%,ms,calls,template) 100.00% 476.128 1 -total 18.96% 90.271 3 Template:Cite_book 11.75% 55.942 1 Template:Pp-semi-vandalism 10.35% 49.266 2 Template:Cn 9.87% 47.004 1 Template:Short_description 9.05% 43.105 1 Template:Pagetype 8.69% 41.353 2 Template:Fix 7.57% 36.060 6 Template:Broken_ref 6.32% 30.079 1 Template:Infobox_machine 5.53% 26.318 4 Template:Category_handler --> </div>`

Answer (score 0):

React will block HTML inserted by javascript by default. If you want to get around this, you need to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop on the parent of your content.

Example:

```
// data from fetch
let data;

return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={data}></div>
```

When you do this, make sure that you trust the HTML source. If you add user generated HTML to your site like this, your site will be vulnerable to XSS attacks.